# Cannot convert project: Error on line -1: Premature end of file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Компьютер перезагрузился, и теперь при открытии проекта идея выкидывает диалоговое окно с такой надписью:

> Cannot convert project: Error on line -1: Premature end of file

что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось удалением `iws` файла.